# is there any api for neo4j like JpaSpecificationExecutor api?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I changed my oracle db to neo4J and I want to use `JpaSpecificationExecutor`, but it's not working for neo4j. Which packet do I have to use for specification filters?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa/) is for *relational* databases. Since Neo4j is a *graph* database, you would need to use [Spring Data Neo4j](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-neo4j/) (SDN) to get something functionally similar to JPA. However, JPA-specific interfaces like `JpaSpecificationExecutor` do not exist in SDN.

Comment: Adding some (probably helpful) content here. There are two options in SDN: QueryDSL support (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/reference/repositories/core-extensions.html#core.extensions.querydsl) or QueryByExample (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/reference/query-by-example.html)